# How do i find a xcode system header file?

Tags: xcode, frameworks, header

I've got a Mac project i want to port to IOS but i cannot resolve some classes.
there is no header file included in the source except Cocoa.h which Ios does not
use. What is the method to find the right header file or framework?

The classes are SecExternalFormat, SecExternalItemType and SecKeychainAttrType

Comment: i tracked the problem to SecImportExport.h which is different from MAC to IOS versions !!!!! why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I always do is a [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3adeveloper.apple.com%20SecKeychainAttrType). For example, in your case I might have done:

`site:developer.apple.com SecKeychainAttrType`

That yields [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html), and then you know you need `Security/Security.h`.

If you downloaded the documentation (I think it comes with Xcode) you could also search it offline.

As for why the API has changed, I think that's beyond the scope of your question.